# Submitting Forms for .NET Sites

Tags: html, .net, forms, perl, submit

I am new in Perl and I am encountering a problem with submitting my form. 
 
The form has a text field for both username and password. And instead of having `button type="submit"`, the form has this `span id="submitButton"` with `onkeypress and onclick`.

Is there a way on clicking or submitting the form using the **`span`** that is in the form? Any advice or suggestions? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is this related to .NET or Perl?

Comment: Hi @reinierpost, we have a .NET site and we are using Perl as a test automation tool. We are using **WWW::Mechanize** module for this but we are stuck on the log in site as it does not go through to the site we intended to go to.
<br/>
`my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
                $response = $mech->get($URL);

                $mech->submit_form(
                fields => {
                UserName => $username,
                Password  => $password,
                },); `

Comment: Ah, thanks, that makes sense. It would help to clarify this in your question. Be aware that `WWW::Mechanize` does not support JavaScript. I advise you to go with Selenium for testing web applications! Specifically, with Perl, I use [Selenium::Remote::Driver](https://metacpan.org/release/Selenium-Remote-Driver)